# How to prevent loading vendors multiple times with code splitting

Tags: webpack, create-react-app

I'm playing around with `create-react-app` and code splitting at the moment. It worked really well until I began to import vendor libraries, which are going to be included in every chunk.

That's my current approach:

**App.js**

```
const HomePage = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./Home.js'),
  LoadingComponent: Loading
});

const AboutPage = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./About.js'),
  LoadingComponent: Loading
});

class App extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
      <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <hr/>

      <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage}/>
      <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

**About.js**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Button = styled.button`
  color: aqua;
`;

class AboutPage extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        About
        <Button>Fooobar!</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AboutPage;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Button = styled.button`
  color: orange;
`;

class HomePage extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Home
        <Button>Fooobar!</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HomePage;
```

So `HomePage` and `AboutPage` are basically the same at the moment, but it's just a playground.

The problem is: the chunk for `HomePage` and `AboutPage` loads the entire `styled-components` package. This should be loaded once, shouldn't it?

[image]

As you can see on the image, `2.chunk.js` and `1.chunk.js` are both 121kb. I thought that code splitting would move `styled-components` to it's own chunk as soon as the packages get's imported multiple times?

For your information: I'm using `create-react-app` and didn't run `eject` so I have no idea what's inside the `webpack` configuration (if this should matter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was the missing `webpackRequireWeakId`.

Instead of ...

```
const HomePage = RouteLoader({ loader: () => import('routes/home') })
```

...I have to use ...

```
const HomePage = RouteLoader({ 
  loader: () => import('routes/home'),
  webpackRequireWeakId: () => require.resolveWeak('routes/home')
})
```

... as described in the documentation of `react-loadable`: https://github.com/thejameskyle/react-loadable#why-are-there-multiple-options-for-specifying-a-component